# How to get file info from a specifically named folder?

Tags: c#

I have a path that contains multiple folders inside it. Each of those folders have multiple subfolders and one of the subfolders in each main folder is named `prog` and inside it is a xml file. Now other subfolders might also have xml files in them but I only want to get the file info of the xml files inside `prog` subfolder in each main folder.

If I do

```
DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\\Testing");

foreach (FileInfo xmlFile in myDir.EnumerateFiles("*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    string myDirectoryName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(xmlFile.Name);
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Then I get all the xml files from all the subfolders in each main folder but I only want xml file inside the `prog` subfolder.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you all .xml files within a prog folder.  This assumes case insensitivity but can be tweaked.

```
DirectoryInfo myDir = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\\Testing");

foreach(FileInfo myFile in myDir.EnumerateFiles(@"*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Where(fi => fi.Directory.Name.Equals("prog")))
{
   // Do something with .xml files in "prog" folder
}
```

Comment: How do I remove case sensitivity in this `Directory.Name.ToLower.Equals` does not work

Comment: fi.Directory.Name.Equals("prog", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of enumerating every XML file recursively, enumerate all the directories of myDir, add "prog" to the path of each, and then enumerate all the XML files within those directories:

```
var progXmlFiles = myDir.EnumerateDirectories()
            .Select(d => Path.Combine(d.FullName, "prog"))
            .SelectMany(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).EnumerateFiles("*.xml"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You said there will be a *\prog* subfolder in each main folder, and inside an xml file. But later you said you only want to get the file info of the xml file(s) (plural).

One way to get all the xml files within *prog* directory is to add this at the start of the for loop:

```
            if (-1 == xmlFile.FullName.IndexOf("\\prog\\"))
                continue;
```

If you only want the .xml files immediately within the *prog* folder, then use this:

```
            if (-1 == xmlFile.FullName.IndexOf("\\prog\\" + xmlFile.Name))
                continue;
```

Here is the output:

```
Finding all XML files under C:\Testing
a_test C:\Testing\a\prog\a_test.xml
b_test C:\Testing\b\prog\b_test.xml
d_test C:\Testing\d\prog\d_test.xml
Done...
Finished, press any key...
```

Here was my setup of test directories, and test files:

```
C:.
├───a
│   ├───a_subdir  \ a_test_error.xml
│   ├───a_subdir2
│   └───prog  \ a_test.xml
├───b
│   ├───b_subdir
│   └───prog  \ b_test.xml
├───c
│   └───prog
├───d
│   ├───d_subdir \ d_test_error.xml
│   └───prog  \ d_test.xml
└───e
```